# Can employment terms be modified while a "fixed-term" contract is active?

Tags: contracts

This is not a specific situation, but a general question regarding contracts in Australia.

Imagine an employee has signed a "fixed-term" contract for x number of years. Can the employer and employee agree to modify the terms of the contract while it is active? For example, can they negotiate a year into the contract for a salary adjustment during the contract, assuming the employer would be happy to do so?

Comment: If you're asking about the legalities, you should ask this in [law.se].

Comment: Changing a contract rarely is an issue as long as both sides are happy with the change.

Answer (score 2):

Changing a contract is itself a (new) contract about the change, so as long as both sides agree, this can be done.

The term limit only specifies how the contract is to be dissolved in the absence of an agreement.